Microwave Trim Kit - Filling in gaps in over-the-range microwaves
I have a space for an over-the-range microwave in my kitchen. The hole is 30 inches. When I tried to have a microwave installed, the door wouldn't open since there is a large cabinet on the right side. The door increased the width by 0.5".
Instead of a 30 inch, I was thinking about buying a 24" microwave, and I see there is a thing called a microwave trim kit. Problem is whenever I look online at one, it seems that the dimensions are 30" but it doesn't tell you what the dimensions of the hole are. Also, these seem to be designed for built-in microwaves.
Any advice on this is appreciated.

typically that just means you need to bring your microwave out farther from the wall.  Adding a picture can help.

Got pics of the location?

Your question is rather vague. Please revise to ask something more specific. See [ask].

You'd buy the trim kit that goes with the microwave you're buying. Manufacturers will make a kit that goes specially with the microwave. (Microwave case sizes vary, so they're not one size fits all.)
One thing to note, a trim kit is often designed to get a smaller microwave into a complete cabinet opening, with wood all around the hole, not necessarily over a range, where the "hole" has no bottom.
The installation instructions will show the model number of the trim kit that you'd get. Or it will be shown on links or PDFs on the microwave model's website page. You may also be able to ask an appliance store what trim kit goes with the microwave.
One might think of adding wood pieces to build out the opening above the range so the smaller microwave can fit, if one cannot find a matching trim kit for an over-the-range situation. However, there is considerable heat from the range to consider, and ranges often have limitations for how close flammable substances like wood can be to the range top surface. An over-the-range microwave's bottom is often far closer to the range surface than wood is allowed to be. Don't violate these limitations in designing any self-built wood fillers. It may be possible to coat the added wood underneath with sheet metal, see the range instructions for if metal-coated wood can be closer than normal, and if so how close. Or it may be possible to build the whole filler out of metal, or scavenge and cut metal parts of a generic trim kit to make side fillers for the microwave. Metal will handle the heat from the range more successfully than wood and can be closer to the range.
A frame challenge: It might be possible to move the range and upper cabinets over a little, so the previous 30" microwave could fit and open correctly. A wood filler would likely be allowed in this case, since the range is moving over, too, and wood to the side of the range is not restricted nearly so much in height as wood over the range.

A frame challenge to make a frame?

Over the range microwaves are designed to fit in a 30" opening between 12" deep upper cabinets.
If your cabinets are deeper than standard 12" then you will need to move the cabinet on the hinge side of the micro over about an inch. and put in a filler between the micro and the cabinet at 12 inches from the back wall.  This will give the room needed for the microwave door to swing, but it may still hit the cabinet before fully opening depending on how deep that cabinet really is. However you will have a usable microwave.
If moving the cabinets is not feasible, you need a smaller microwave.
